# JavaFx. What property of Scrollpane defines how far it is scrollable independantly of screen size

Tags: java, javafx, scroll

If I create a scroll pane, let's say i want to be able to scroll futher that the size of the screen, (till the eternity whatever) how would i define how far i can go.

I have a program with a scrollPane and when i just call the program i actually cannot scroll anywhere, only if i resize the window (make it smaller) i can scroll.

the question is: What property should i change to define how far the scrollPane can go.

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
final ScrollPane scrollable = new ScrollPane();

Scene scene = new Scene(scrollable, windowWidth, windowHeight);
```

Comment: Isn't this determined by the relative sizes of the scroll pane's content and the scroll pane's viewport? So you would just put something in the scroll pane that is bigger than the scroll pane itself?

Comment: Yes if you add a container and set it to the size you want to be able to scroll to whatever the size of the container is

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what @James_D said its as big as the content inside

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setPrefSize(300,300);
        Label promptLabel = new Label("Keep Scrolling!!");
        vbox.getChildren().add(promptLabel);
        vbox.setMinHeight(3000);
        scrollPane.setContent(vbox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```